# Scanner takes blank as input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to get two string inputs into a string array

```
String[] b = new String[n];
```

by using scanner but the scanner automatically takes blank value in 
`b[0]`.i.e. it skips the first loop.

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int no = 0;
        int n = scn.nextInt();
        String[] b = new String[n];

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the string");
            b[j] = scn.nextLine();
        }
```

the output occurs like

```
2
Enter

Enter
abc
```

can anyone suggest me why this problem occurs??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `nextInt()` does not read the `\n` in your input. This is then read by your `nextLine()`

---

More explanation,
When you enter a number when prompted by the `nextInt()` call. You type a number and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> This makes your input look like this

> 10`\n`

`nextInt()` reads only the `10` and leaves out `\n`.

Then, your `nextLine()` reads only the `\n`.

This explains your output.
You can get the expected output by having an extra `nextLine()` after the `nextInt()`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods) for more information on it.

Comment: @vineethPrabhakaran Welcome !